# Equivalent of Nimbus JOSE+JWT in Apex

Tags: apex

Does any of you know whether there is an equivalent implementation of Nimbus JOSE+JWT in Apex?

What I'm trying to do is port some Java code written using Nimbus JOSE+JWT to generate five part encoded and encrypted JWT to Apex. I think the platform support available JWS, JWT and Crypto classes is limited to achieve this.

Comment: Actually, what I want to know is how to encrypt a JWT claims string using a stored certificate. Are the methods in Crypto class can handle this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was unable to find an equivalent of Nimbus JOSE+JWT for Salesforce Apex. Infact Crypto class in Salesforce has quite limited functionality. It doesn't support asymmetric Public/Private key encryption at the moment.

Comment: For 2023 does it support asymmetric public/private key encryption now?